# Do headless fragments call onPause()?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm thinking of using a headless fragment to keep track of changes in a dataset and update to a SQLite database periodically.  Based on the commonly-available information on the fragment lifecycle, it is suggested that persistent data storage be updated at `onPause()`.  However, `onPause()` is usually called when a fragment or activity is being hidden from view, which is obviously not going to happen to a persistent headless fragment.  But is `onPause()` ever called by a headless fragment?  If so, when?  What's the best time to save data from a headless fragment?

Answer (score 0):

A `Fragment's` `onPause()` method is usually tied to its containing `Activity's` `onPause()`, so yes, a headless `Fragment` can be paused when its parent `Activity` is hidden from view.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onPause()

Comment: See, I'm still having trouble figuring out that behaviour.  What does it mean for a headless fragment to be paused, considering that it has no UI?  If I'm using the fragment as a wrapper for an `AsyncTask`, will the task halt if it gets paused?  Throw an exception?  Keep running as though nothing happened?

Comment: You might release resources or whatever you wanted to do in this case. And reinitialise them and get things going again when the Activity and hence the fragments are resumed. These resources are not necessarily user interface resources.